# What is the distance between staples when using a running board under floor joists in an unfinished crawl space

Tags: electrical

What is the max distance between staples when using a running board to cross floor joists in an unfinished crawl space?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, unless there are other circumstances, about 4.5' but  ...here is the rule:

2020 Code Language:

334.30 Securing and Supporting. Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall be supported and secured by staples, cable ties listed and identified for securement and support, or straps, hangers, or similar fittings designed and installed so as not to damage the cable, at intervals not exceeding 1.4 m (4 ½ ft) and within 300 mm (12 in.) of every cable entry into enclosures such as outlet boxes, junction boxes, cabinets, or fittings. The cable length between the cable entry and the closest cable support shall not exceed 450 mm (18 in.). Flat cables shall not be stapled on edge.

Comment: I agree that 4.5 feet is the answer, but it makes no sense. If I staple my wires to the bottom of the floor joist, they are 16 inches apart. If I staple them to the running board, they will be three times that distance apart and surely sage much more.

Comment: So you're planning on a running board **UNDER** the joists? If so, why?  Also, why not just drill the joists and not worry about staples at all?   If you do wish to us a running board, the code is the minimum, nothing says you couldn't install twice or three times as many staples.